# qplot dynamic plotting

Tags: r, dynamic, ggplot2

I would like to create dynamic plotting over given dates, ie i want the plots appear one after another through specific dates when the code is run. This code seems to work with `plot` function but not with `qplot`.

any ideas?

thanks in advance,

`x` with headings `t`, `date`, `AUM`, `profit`

```
windows(5,5)
dev.set()
for (i in 1:10){
  z <- x[x$t == i,]
  a <- unique(z$date)
  qplot(z$AUM,z$profit,main=a,xlim=range(0:2.5e+08),ylim=range(0:6e+06))
}
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data to make your example reproducible ?

Comment: Have you looked at the animation package?

Comment: You need to add a `print()`, i.e. `print(qplot(...))`. the reason is that `ggplot2` uses grid graphics which requires a print call.  This is [R FAQ 7.16](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-the-output-not-printed-when-I-source_0028_0029-a-file_003f).

Comment: it works now Andrie. the animation package seems to be quite useful as well. many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `print()` call, i.e. `print(qplot(...))`.

The reason is that ggplot2 uses grid graphics which requires a print call.

```
print(qplot(z$AUM,z$profit,main=a,xlim=range(0:2.5e+08),ylim=range(0:6e+06)))
```

---

This is [R FAQ 7.16](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-the-output-not-printed-when-I-source_0028_0029-a-file_003f).